# UWP - How do I convert date from calendar date picker to specified date format

Tags: uwp

I have in my project couple of calendar date picker controls. I am using code below to get date from them

[image]

How can I parse this to specific DateTime format ? For example to dd.mm.yyyy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DateTime.ToString(String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tostring(v=vs.110).aspx)  method can define custom format for `DateTime`. So we need to get out the `DateTime` type value from the [`CalendarDatePicker.Date`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.calendardatepicker.date.aspx) property. [Nullable structure](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/b3h38hb0.aspx) has value property can get a valid underlying value. Code as follows can parse the date:

```
var date = arrivalCalendarDatePicker.Date;
DateTime time = date.Value.DateTime;
var formatedtime = time.ToString("dd.mm.yyyy");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(formatedtime);
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! It works, but when I try to add years using this `time.AddYears(10);`, it doesn´t works, can you tell me why please ?

Comment: You probably mean `.ToString("dd.MM.yyyy")`. 'm' is for minutes, 'M' is for month, see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx. That being said, I would use `.ToString("d")`, which automatically adapts to different cultures. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx.

Comment: Thank  you, so can you tell me please, how can I add years to **time** ?

Comment: @Aellopos  [AddYears](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.addyears(v=vs.110).aspx) method return a new  datetime based on the original, not update the `time`. Please get the new time by code `var newtime= time.AddYears(10);`, and use the `newtime`, it will show the time already add 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `CalendarDatePicker.Date` property is a nullable `DateTimeOffset`. You can access the associated `DateTime` object and [get an array of strings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyk2998w(v=vs.110).aspx) that represent the date in various formats like this:

```
DateTimeOffset myDateTimeOffset = myCalendarDatePicker.Date ?? default(DateTimeOffset);
DateTime myDateTime = myDateTimeOffset.DateTime;
var formatArray = myDateTime.GetDateTimeFormats();
string desiredDateTimeFormat = formatArray[index];
```

Take a look over what [formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fyk2998w(v=vs.110).aspx) are returned in the array of strings in order to choose your desired one.

Comment: When I try to write this `DateTimeOffset myDateTimeOffset = DatumPrvniRegVozCR.Date;` it shows me the error: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.DateTimeOffset?' to 'System.DateTimeOffset'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: my bad, I edited the code, it should work now. There will be a fallback value when myCalendarDatePicker.Date is null, so myDateTimeOffset will always have a value. You may want to wrap all this code into an if(myCalendarDatePicker.Date != null).